# How to compare emails using MD5 hashes

Tags: java, hash, jakarta-mail, md5sum

I've heard MD5 hashes can be used to compare contents of eg a file. The `MimePart` class in the JavaMail library also contains a `setContentMD5()` method, but I couldn't find an example for using it. Can I use it to compare email content using the hashes (and verify there was no loss of data during the download)? Of which part should I then generate the MD5 hash?

Also, `the getContentMD5()` doesn't work when I use IMAP (although the header is actually present).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Content-MD5 header is an optional MIME header set by the creator of the message.  If the header exists on some of your messages and your IMAP server isn't returning it, that's a bug in your IMAP server.

Given that the header is optional, and at least in my mailbox there are no messages with that header, it's probably not going to help you with your problem.

Comment: Ok, but do you know if there is a documentation of the header? Is there no official rule for of which text/bytes you can create the hash?

Comment: I mean, I think it can only be applied to bodyparts with text or attachments, am I right?